# How to sniff specific packets using python module Scapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I want to capture ONLY deauth packets, and then work on them. I was able to generate deauth attack using scapy, but dont knot how to capture it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sniff all packets and check whether they are `deauth` packets.

Based upon [this concise link](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/03/wi-fi-sniffer-in-10-lines-of-python.html), and since `deauth` packet is of type `0` and subtype `0xC`, as mentioned [here](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/wireless_lan/wlan_packet_types), this is what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

def PacketHandler(pkt):     
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 0xC:
        print "Deauth packet sniffed: %s" % (pkt.summary())

sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

You have to set your interface into monitor mode beforehand. The exact method to do so depends on your operating system. Here is [a good link](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode) that explains how this can be done for several popular operating systems.

In order to sniff on several channels, you should continuously switch between channels in the background.

---

For your reference, here is the [official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) on the `sniff` function:

```
sniff(prn=None, lfilter=None, count=0, store=1, offline=None, L2socket=None,
timeout=None) Sniffs packets from the network and return them in a
packet list. This function can have many parameters:

    count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity.

    store: wether to store sniffed packets or discard them. When you only
    want to monitor your network forever, set store to 0.

    prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned, it is dis-
    played. For instance you can use prn = lambda x: x.summary().

    lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine. if further
    action may be done. For instance, you can use lfilter = lambda
    x: x.haslayer(Padding)

    offline: pcap file to read packets from, instead of sniffing them. In this
    case, BPF filter won’t work.

    timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None).

    L2socket: you can provide a supersocket for sniffing instead of the one
    from conf.L2listen.
```